# Python code environment with input and output

Tags: environments, python

I am trying to set up a simple environment for displaying Python code and output. I want the output to be bold font. I have written the following

```
\newenvironment{code}[2]{   
\begin{shaded}
    \noindent\ttfamily{#1}\\{\noindent\ttfamily{\bf #2} \normalfont}
\end{shaded} }
```

The first argument is the input and the second is the output. Here's an example.

```
\code{w = True; type(w)}{bool}
```

What I would like to fix is the following

- I would like to put `>>>` in front of the output
- I would to remove the empty line if the output is empty
- The output is not `ttfamily` despite the `\ttfamily{#2}` and I do not know why.

Comment: You are aware that `\ttfamily ` does not take arguments, that `\bf` should not be used, that the standard tt font does not have bold tt

Comment: I suspected that. How would I get bold font in a fixed width font ?

Comment: See fx http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use packages that already do this (e.g. minted with pycon lexer)?

Comment: I recommend using the [listings](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package.

Comment: I have used listings but it is really just for source code. It does not allow me to show input and output in different fonts.